# Given $M_t$ a martingale show $E\left[\left( \left| \int_0^t M_s dB_s \right|^2 \right) \right]^{1/8} \le E[M_t^2]^{1/8} t^{1/8}$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, isometry

Given $M_t$ a martingale, $\lim_{t \to \infty}E[M_t]^2=0$, and $t \le 1$, show $$E\left[\left( \left| \int_0^t M_s dB_s \right|^2 \right) \right] \le E[M_t^2] t$$

The first step is that I want to use Itô's isometry to show (I am a little unsure about the absolute value here but I think it works like this)

$$E\left[\left( \left| \int_0^t M_s dB_s \right|^2 \right) \right] = E\left[\left(  \int_0^t \left| M_s \right|^2 ds  \right) \right]$$

Now since we have the traditional integral we can move the expected value inside the integral.

$$=\left(  \int_0^t E\left[\left| M_s \right|^2\right] ds  \right) $$

If this has been correct until here, my biggest confusion is now how to evaluate this integral. Considering the desired answer it seems like we treat the integrand here as a "constant" in the traditional sense so I would just have $\int_0^t E\left[\left| M_s \right|^2\right] ds = tE[\left| M_t \right|^2] - 0E[\left| M_0 \right|^2]$ but I doubt it. Can someone help me here? Thanks.

Comment: Is it necessary to add $\frac{1}{8}$ on all the terms?

Comment: No, I guess not, this was just a piece of a larger problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
E\left[\left(  \int_0^t M_s dB_s  \right)^2 \right] &= E\left[\int_0^t M_s^2 ds\right]   \\
&=\int_0^t E\left[  M_s^2   \right] ds \le \int_0^t E\left[  M_t^2   \right] ds =E\left[  M_t^2   \right]t  \\ 
\end{align}

Here, we use the fact that $E[M_s^2] \le E[M_t^2]$, effectively, applying the Jensen's inequality
$$M_s^2 =E[M_t|\mathcal{F}_s]^2 \le E[M_t^2|\mathcal{F}_s]$$
$$\implies E[M_s^2] \le E[E[M_t^2|\mathcal{F}_s]] = E[M_t^2]$$

Comment: Yes thank you, this piece with Jensen's inequality is the piece I was missing. Replacing $M_s$ with $M_t$ allows us to treat it as a constant.

Comment: Just to confirm, the step where we say $E[M_t|F_s]^2 \le E[M_t^2|F_s]$ is Jensen's inequality because $f(x)=x^2$ is a convex function, right? Then the only part I'm still not quite sure about is the last step $E[E[M_t^2|F_s]] \le E[M_t^2]$? The double expectation is throwing me off.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind about the inequality as the last step, it's just a typo. I modified it. About the Jensen's inequality, what you wrote is exact.  $f(x) =x^2$ is a convex function.